# scikit-learn deprecated GMM.eval() replacement

Tags: python, scikit-learn, gmm

The `eval()` method under `sklearn.mixture.GMM` from the scikit-learn version 0.11 is deprecated. Is there a similar method or a workaround in the newest version 0.19.2 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current method to get the responsibilities is [`predict_proba()`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.mixture.GaussianMixture.html#sklearn.mixture.GaussianMixture.predict_proba)

> `predict_proba()`:
>           Predict posterior probability of each component given the data.

Now you may think that the description does not say responsibilities. But this is what you need.

The move from GMM to GaussianMixture class has been discussed thoroughly here:

- https://github.com/taborlab/FlowCal/issues/230
- https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/wiki/GSoC-2015-Proposal:-Improve-GMM-module

And the answer you need is described here:

- https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/7953

You may see some difference in results as described by the author in [this comment](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/7953#issuecomment-263731714)

> The old one had a pretty strong regularization, the new one does not (by default).

You can check the source code too to verify that this indeed returns the responsibilities.

Comment: To replace the following `logprob, resp = gmm.eval(X)` in the scikit-learn v0.19.2  one would use `logprob = gmm.score_samples(X)` for the log-probabilities `resp  = gmm.predict_proba(X)` to predict posterior probabilities/ responsibilities.

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](http://jaquesgrobler.github.io/online-sklearn-build/modules/generated/sklearn.mixture.GMM.html#sklearn.mixture.GMM.eval) of an older scikit-learn version you can read the following:

> DEPRECATED: GMM.eval was renamed to GMM.score_samples in 0.14 and will
>   be removed in 0.16.

So I think you should use `score_samples()`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but using the `score_samples()` would only solve the problem partially. `eval()` returns the log probabilities and the responsibilities whereas in the latest version 0.19.2 the `score_samples()` only returns the log probabilities.

Comment: It seems like there is no 1:1 substitute

Comment: Do have an idea on how to compute the responsibilities using the existing methods?

Comment: Sorry I have no idea and I think there is no easy way to solve it except using an old scikit-learn version where evil() is still supported

Answer (score 1):

Eval(X)

**Parameters :**

X: array_like, shape (n_samples, n_features) : List of n_features-dimensional data points. Each row corresponds to a single data point.

**Returns :**

logprob: array_like, shape (n_samples,) : Log probabilities of each data point in X

responsibilities: array_like, shape (n_samples, n_components) :

Posterior probabilities of each mixture component for each observation

Clearly , there is no workaround in the newer definition , it is the same and quite concise definition